# Run SQL query with minimum match criteria in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, match

Is it possible to write a sql query which returns results based on minimum matching criteria. For example

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column <matches 80% of value 'abbey Road'>
```

Basically the query should return rows containg column value 'abbey road' and also 'abbey mahatma gandhi road' by matching abbey and road in the string

Comment: You could have a look at full-text search feature of the SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select * from TableName 
where ColumnName Like ('%'+Replace(@texttosearch,' ','%')+'%')
```

Make sure Text To Search is trim already before sending to this query.The above query return result for all string which contain abbey road irreaspective of there position.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the LIKE operator with wildcards. The following query will match any string that contains abbey and road in that order.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%abbey%road%';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have your words in the string with spaces, you could match just by string:

```
select *
from test1
where col1 like '%' + replace(@text, ' ', '%');
```

If you have your words in some table, you could do this:

```
select t.col1
from test1 as t
    inner join @words as w on t.col1 like '%' + w.word + '%'
group by t.col1
having count(w.word) = (select count(*) from @words)
```

see [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01165/4) example to try this queries